# Visual Studio 2013 - The referenced component cound not be found

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I've put together a solution with multiple projects, checked it into team studio, colleagues checked it out but thier build fails with ALL the references marked with a warning e.g. 'The referenced component System.Data could not be found'

If I look in the project files I see all my references with the form

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Topshelf"> 
    <HintPath>..\packages\Topshelf.3.1.4\lib\net40-full\Topshelf.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference> 
  ... 
 </ItemGroup>
```

ALL the paths resolve to a dll in the packages directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do the paths resolve on their machines? Are you excluding the package directory (or DLLs) from source control? Have you tried restoring the packages from the Nuget package manager after checking out from source control?

Comment: yes, the paths are (..\packages) local to the project directory.
If I enable nuget restore the problem is resolved, but I dont see why I need allow all the machines access to nuget, is not the packages directory sufficent?

Comment: Look at the System.Data reference and see if you have anything forcing VS to load a particular version, also make sure that you have the same update level as everyone else. Looks like you have something that is making your references incompatible.